# Call requires API level 9 (current is 8 => WRONG), android.media.audiofx.Visualizer related. (Picture Inside)

Tags: android, api, audio, media, visualizer

Sorry I couldn't make the title more clear, so here is my problem : I'm using a source code from this project ( https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer ) and have a really weird problem.
When I use the code without doing any modification, it works without any problem, I can run the program on my android device.

But when I add this code in my own program (and adapt everything), I have this error message :
**Class requires API level 9 (current min is 8): android.media.audiofx.Visualizer**

Given the fact that I have modified my Manifest with this, I don't have a clue what's wrong:

> > ```
> >     < uses-sdk
> >     android:minSdkVersion="9" 
> >     android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
> > ```

I have read similar posts but nothing worked so far, and I'm really upset by the fact that the original program works perfectly, and trouble starts with my own version.

Thanks in advance if you have any idea !

See you[image: Picture from my problem box]

Comment: This is because you are using some function that requires API 9 and your project sdk is 8 change the sdk to 9

Comment: How can I do ? I have modified the "Project Build Target" to Android 2.3.3 (API 10) and mentioned in my manifest that 9 should be the minimum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that maybe you should Clean your project and then try back again. Sometimes Eclipse does such silly things even everything is ok.

Comment: It worked! Cleaning the project made the errors disappear and my app is working now! Thanks for the suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your android SDK.
In Android SDK Manager you will find Extras in the last. You need to update the **Android Support Library** to revision 11.

Thanks

Comment: OR you can modify the Manifest.xml file android:minSdkVersion="8"